# SSL ruins affiliate images

Tags: ssl

I just installed SSL to my webpage. The problem is, that it destroys the affiliate ads images, as you can see here: https://pengepiloten.dk/bredbaand/

Now, I have to download the image and upload it the server and do it manually, each time. It is alot of work to do each time, as you can see here: https://pengepiloten.dk/sms-laan/

How  can i fix it?

Comment: Can you add some more information so this question has value even when the issue is solved (and cannot be seen at that link any more)? Why are they getting ruined? (There seem to be https links to those images, where do they come from?) What are you uploading where to fix it?

Comment: The images are hosted on a 3rd party site using which is using a self-signed certificate. Chrome is rejecting them with the error net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE. He can download them himself and upload them to his own server to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

The domain https://impr.adservicemedia.dk/ is using a self-signed certificate. Chrome does not like this (and it shouldn't). If you own https://impr.adservicemedia.dk/ yourself, you can purchase an SSL certificate from a 3rd party. Otherwise you will need to keep uploading them to your own server.

Maybe you could find a way to script that so your aren't doing it by hand.

Comment: Sorry, I dont get.. 

It is a self-signed cerfificate?

I personally purchased my ssl-certificat from third party. 

How can they sign af SSL certificate to themself? I didnt know, that was possible. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help!

As you say, there is something wrong with their certificate. They didnt renew it 420 days ago. That is why it doesnt work!

I think it is because they changed their main domain name to Adservice.dk instead of Adservicemedia.dk. Therefor they have not renewed the old certificate for the old domain, but they are still hosting the ad-images at the old domain.

That is why my domain rejects the ad-images. It can't confirm the certificate.